# How do I specify DISTINCT when using JPA 2?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0, distinct, resultset

I'm using Hibernate 4.1.0.Final, MySQL 5.5, and JPA 2.0.  When returning values from my JPA query, how do I specify a "distinct" clause without rewriting my function to be an SQL (or JPQL) statement?  Below if how I have coded my JPA method so far ...

```
final List<ReturnedObject> foundReturnedObjects = new ArrayList<ReturnedObject>();

final CriteriaBuilder builder = m_entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
final CriteriaQuery<ReturnedObject> query = builder.createQuery(ReturnedObject.class);

final Root<JoinedObject> JoinedObject = query.from(JoinedObject.class);
final Join<JoinedObject, ReturnedObject> ReturnedObject = JoinedObject.join(JoinedObject_.returnedObject);
if (params != null && !params.isEmpty()) 
{
    query.where(JoinedObject.get(JoinedObject_.organization).in(params));
    query.select(ReturnedObject);
    foundReturnedObjects.addAll(m_entityManager.createQuery(query).getResultList());
} // if
return foundReturnedObjects;
```

However, the problem is duplicate items could potentially be returned.  Note, I realize I could transfer all the results to a java.util.Set, but this question is specifically about executing the SQL with a DISTINCT clause instead of doing that work after the query has returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That can be done by using [distinct](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html#distinct%28boolean%29) method, which can be found from CriteriaQuery itself:

```
query.distinct(true);
```